# vue-hotel-datepicker API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

API

⚠️ In order to open/close the datepicker from an external element, such as a button make sure to set closeDatepickerOnClickOutside to false

hideDatepicker()
Hide datepicker

showDatepicker()
Show datepicker

toggleDatepicker()
Toggle datepicker

I would ike to open and close datepicker from external element but cant understand how,
I dont understand anything from this. what does this mean can anyone explain. 
I tried this codes but didnt make it work

```
<HotelDatePicker 
  :show-datepicker= "showDatepicker"
  :showDatepicker="showDatepicker"
  :isOpen="showDatepicker"
  style="z-index:20000"
  :hoveringTooltip="true"
  :closeDatepickerOnClickOutside="false"
  format="D MMMM">
</HotelDatePicker>
```

this is the page for documentation
https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker

Comment: Did you try adding a ref to the component and using this.$refs.[ref].showDatepicker() ? 

e.g. <HotelDatePicker ref="myDatePicker"> </HotelDatePicker> 
and in the @click method: this.$refs.myDatePicker.showDatePicker()

Comment: This works thanks for answer.